# “code .” Not working in Command Line for Visual Code Studio on Windows10

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

[This is the screenshot for it, from my cmd terminal on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxJwi.png) "Code." does not work anymore on my cmd. Need assistance here. Looks like it does not know that command anymore. 
Tried to solve it with Ctrl + Shift+P to go to "Shell command" but also this is not displayed.

The result is german and means:"The command 'code .' is either wrongly written or could not be found."

Comment: In what way does it not work?  What is the exact error message?  Perhaps you could add a screenshot including the error.

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for commenting. Yes, I put a screenshot here. See above, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that `code` is not in your `PATH` variable.

Try changing this using

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<Path\to\vscode\directory>
```

where `<Path\to\vscode\directory>` is the absolute path of the directory to the executeable of `code`.